# Adding post id inside a wordpress database query?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have a custom wp database I am trying to add the ID of the post the form was submitted from.

```
function add_custom_settings() {



if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    // Get WPDB Object
    global $wpdb;

    // Table name
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "custom";


        // Execute query
        $wpdb->query(
            $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO $table_name
                                (post_id, name, data, date_c, date_m)
                            VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %d, %d)",
                            '',
                            '',
                            time(),
                            time()
                            )
        );

    // Empty
    $static = array();

    // ID
    $id = mysqli_insert_id();

    // DB data
    $post_id = the_ID();
    $name = $wpdb->escape($static['properties']['title']);
    $data = $wpdb->escape(json_encode($static));

    // Update
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $table_name SET
                post_id = '$post_id',
                name = '$name',
                data = '$data',
                date_m = '".time()."'
              ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");


    die();
}



}
```

Inside the query you will notice I am trying to insert `the_ID()` into the post_id column. It doesnt return the ID, I assume because the function is not associated with the post, echoing `the_ID()` inside the form works, just not in the function.

Once I figure this out I can finally get this thing working... its been tough, hope someone can help!

The form is quite long but here is a snippet..

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" method="post">  

<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1"

     //Form Data Here

    <input type="submit" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" />//echoing the ID here works.. 
</form>
```

Comment: CAN ANYONE SHED SOME LIGHT?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but here what I think

First `the_ID();` is used to displays the ID of the current post within the loop, it does not returns the value of the post id.

To get the post id use: `get_the_ID()`.

Second, if you are outside the loop, then neither simply `the_ID()` nor `get_the_ID()` is going to work, you have to provide the post id manually or by receiving it using GET or POST method.